# Finding (∂U/∂V )T = n^2a/V^2 for a van der Waals gas

Tags: physical-chemistry, van-der-waals-behavior

$\displaystyle dU = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V dT + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T dV \to dU = C_v dT - C_v\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_U dV$

Not sure what I do here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For clarity  I have converted your equation to MathJax, please check that it is correct.

Comment: The title and the question are not related to one another

Comment: I guess they are related via an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The more general equation you are looking for is called the thermodynamic equation of state. You can start from the differential form of U according to the 1st + 2nd laws of thermodynamics for pV work only:

$$dU = TdS-pdV$$

Taking the derivative wrt V at constant T

$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T= T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T-p$$

At this point you want to use the Maxwell relation

$$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V= \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T$$

(which follows from the Helmholtz energy being a state function) so that

$$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T= T \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V-p \tag{tes}$$

This last expression is the thermodynamic equation of state.

The final step is to evaluate $\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V$ for the van der Waals equation of state.

Answer (score 0):

The equations for du you listed in the question description can be derived by applying the definition of constant volume heat capacity and using a cyclic relation. Derivation of constant volume heat capacity can be found here : https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node18.html.

Refer to cyclic relationships which fall under the topic of Maxwell relations to understand how to convert the second term to the appropriate form.